# How can I change the default render directory to a relative directory?

Tags: interface

By default, Blender renders into /temp.
How I can I make it render into a a subdirectory of wherever my .blend is, like //rendered_video\

Comment: https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/files/relative_paths.html you may find your answers here?

Comment: @hawkenfox I know how to make a relative path, but not how to set it as the default for new blends.

Comment: Save user preferences with `Ctrl`+`U` to make new blends to have typed relative path as default one. Beware though that if you create some project which uses another path it should be edited once more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with a new file, set the render output to `//rendered_video/` and then select *File->Save Startup File*

[image]

For version 2.8

[image]

Blender will now use that output location every time you create a new blend.

You may also want to set [Render Output in the File Preferences](https://www.blender.org/manual/preferences/file.html#file-paths) this setting will set the default render output path used when you create a new scene.

Answer (score 1):

Relative Paths
Many Blender files reference external images or other linked .blend files. A path tells Blender where to look for these files. If the external files are moved, the blend file that references them won’t look right.

When you specify one of these external files, the default option is to make the path relative. Blender stores a partial path evaluated relative to the directory location of the referencing blend file. This choice helps when you need to reorganize folders or move your files.

With a relative path you can move the .blend file to a new location provided the externally linked files are moved along with it. For example you could send someone a folder that contains a .blend file and a sub-folder of external images that it references.

Most file selection windows provide a Relative Path check box, or when you type in a path into a text field, use a double slash prefix (//) to make it so.

Reference taken from [Here](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/files/relative_paths.html) also read [File Preferences](https://www.blender.org/manual/preferences/file.html).