# How to set Output path correctly for a Single Image render?

Tags: rendering, interface

I know this is such a basic question, hence I cannot find similar question to this.

I've set up Render Output file in Preferences and Clicked Save Preferences:

[image]

But after rendering nothing appears in the folder. Why?

I've found this other question, for blender 2.7, but my Render Panel has no option to put a Render Output Path:

[image]

As Answer from this post suggests:

[How can I change the default render directory to a relative directory?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44011/how-can-i-change-the-default-render-directory-to-a-relative-directory/44032#44032)

[image]

**But my Render Panel does not have that option**:

[image]
**Plus**:

I'd like to set the width and height of my rendered image to: 1200 * 628 (for a Facebook PPL). How do I do that so it is the default size output?

**UPDATE 1**

Still cannot see any image in my path:

I've change the path, should I do something else?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you have your path wrong, according to me a path never has `//` at start!

Comment: @Yash this is the path I''ve set:  `D:\blender_projects\outputs\` ... where are the 
   `//`???

Comment: As per your last screenshot your path is `//render_video/`

Comment: @Yash that last screen shot is not from my computer but for an Answer to a Similar question. But I don't have that option on my Render Panel.

Comment: I thought it was yours, anyways check my answer below!

Comment: Check my edit, it is for Blender 2.8!

Comment: If you render only one frame, it will not be saved directly to the folder you have to it manually!

Comment: You can save it by clicking on **Image** option located at the left of **Render result** drop down and click **Save as**!

Comment: So you can only save a video output automatically from Blender? If it is a single image you have to do it manually? Weird.

Comment: Yeah but If you select output images for animation then they will be saved automatically!

Comment: Could you edit you answer so it is clear that besides putting the right path, if you render only one image you still need to save it manually? (for future readers).

Comment: Okay, I have edited ;)

Comment: Rendering still image by default does not save anything to the output path, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6772/1245 though this is part of another question. There are some ways to workaround that

Comment: @Yash `//` symbols at the start of the path usually means relative location, in case of Blender output path it is treated as "put render output to wherever project file is saved to"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are Rendering single image Image using the **Render**> Render Image menu or <kbd>f12</kbd>, Blender will not save the image automatically.

[image]

You have to save it manually, by clicking **Image** option located at the left of **Render Result** dropdown and select **Save as** (or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> while in the image editor).

[image]

A new window will open where you can choose where to save the file.

*If you want to save the image automatically* you can render as animation.

Set the frame range to a single frame.

[image]

Then render using the **Render animation** option or <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Note that 2.8 has different panel for output.

Dimensions and frame range can be set there as well.

[image]

Comment: please, see my update 1.

Comment: @cegaton lol my answer is just lost :p

Comment: @Yash I just added images for clarity, the main answer is at the top. It is still your answer, and you deserve the credit and reputation. You can always roll it back or re-edit if you disagree with the edits, or find them unheplful.  : )

Comment: @cegaton I was not able to add images because my Blender was not with me, anyways, thanks for the edit ;)